# close AddThis menu with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, addthis

I am looking for a way to close the AddThis menu with JavaScript if the user indicates he is not willing to visit an external site. Basically I want to trigger the same method that would occur if the user moves his mouse away from the menu.

I can destroy the Add This menu in the DOM, but that creates errors in the AddThis script and the menu cannot be reopened.

I have tried addthis.menu.close() to no avail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try a [.blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) event on the menu. Im guessing this could possibly trigger the event that would otherwise be triggered on a defocus of the element (a blur).